# How to echo html+php in php?

Tags: php, html

i have a code in my php file:

```
   <?php
       echo (is_int(($index-1)/$rpp) && $index != 1) ? 
     "</tbody></table></li><li><table class='rc-list-table' width='100%'><tbody><tr>" :
      "<tr>" ; 
    ?>
```

i want to add following codes before `<tbody>` tag:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
    <th><?php _e('Q.No', 'r-check'); ?></th>
                <?php
                 for ($i=0; $i < $dim ; $i++) { ?>
    <th><?php echo chr($i+65); ?></th>
        <?php } ?>

    </tr>
</thead>
```

**that is i want to get final format of the code like:**

```
<?php
           echo (is_int(($index-1)/$rpp) && $index != 1) ? 
         "</tbody></table></li><li><table class='rc-list-table' width='100%'><thead><tr><th><?php _e('Q.No', 'r-check'); ?></th><?php for ($i=0; $i < $dim ; $i++) { ?><th><?php echo chr($i+65); ?></th><?php } ?></tr></thead><tbody><tr>" : "<tr>" ; 
        ?>
```

i tried several but problem with for loop. thanks in advance...

Comment: Am I right to think that you have a problem with "?>" ?If you do then change it to "?" . ">".

Answer (score 0):

`colon syntax` makes your code much cleaner.

```
<thead>
    <tr>
    <th><?php _e('Q.No', 'r-check'); ?></th>
    <?php for ($i=0; $i < $dim ; $i++): ?>
        <th><?php echo chr($i+65); ?></th>
    <?php endfor; ?>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just I understand your question. How about the following?

```
<?
   if(is_int(($index-1)/$rpp) && $index != 1):
?>
</tbody></table></li><li><table class='rc-list-table' width='100%'>
<thead>
    <tr>
    <th><?php _e('Q.No', 'r-check'); ?></th>
        <?php
            for ($i=0; $i < $dim ; $i++) : ?>
    <th><?php echo chr($i+65); ?></th>
        <?php endfor; ?>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody><tr><tr>
<? endif;?>
```

Comment: ok. its enough for the purpose. but is it not possible to make echo out as the format mentioned in question?